# How to safely construct a C++ object in malloc'ed memory with a header object

Tags: c++, memory

I want to construct arbitrary C++ objects in memory returned by another allocator (which usually calls realloc internally). I know it's generally fine to do a placement new into malloc'ed memory. However, I want all C++ objects to have another common object before it in contiguous allocated memory. This header object will contain information about the following C++ object. I don't know that it is safe, from an alignment standpoint, to allocate (sizeof(header) + sizeof(type)) memory and then construct type at (mem + sizeof(header)). I think it isn't because (mem + sizeof(header)) isn't guaranteed to be properly aligned for type.

I have mulled possibilities such as generating a template type that declares the header followed by type T and allocating `sizeof(ObjPlusHeader<T>)`. However, the problem is that the structure will appear in another part of my code as a void* (mandated by an external library I don't control) so I have to KNOW what to cast it to. I want to cast to Header* not to `ObjectPlusHeader<???>*`.

I know with Standard Layout types I can cast an object to a pointer to its first member. However, T is not necessarily Standard Layout in which case `ObjectPlusHeader<T>` will not be Standard Layout either even if Header is. I also considered making the wrapper template derive publicly from Header and privately from T instead of containing T. However, it still wouldn't be legal to cast the void* directly to a Header* without first casting to the actual type that was stored which I will not know.

What I want is contiguous memory allocated by the allocator (essentially realloc) where I know Header is at the beginning and the arbitrary C++ object follows at some properly aligned address >= mem + sizeof(Header) that I know and can store in the Header. So given the void* I can cast it to Header* and obtain the object. However, I'm unsure about the potential alignment issues.

Comment: If the objects should be tied together you store them as a `std::pair`

Comment: @NathanOliver. Indeed but is it safe to cast std::pair<Header, T>* to Header* when T is not necessarily Standard Layout? You see, the second part of the problem is that I won't know the actual type of the pair. I need a guarantee that  I can cast to Header* and go from there.

Comment: Why don't you just get the required alignment via [alignof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof) and adjust the pointer accordingly? i.e. add the correct amount of padding yourself.

Comment: @authentec What about subclassing? Casting to/from a (template) subclass of `Header` is definitely allowed.

Comment: @o11c The problem with that is that I have to store the full (most derived) object as a void*. Even if Header is a base of the full object I am not allowed to cast that void* directly to Header*. I have to static_cast to the full object first and I will not know it since it will depend on T.

Comment: @authentec That depends on how you create the `void*`. If you create it by casting the `Header*` instead of the object directly, it's fine.

Comment: @o11c True, but unfortunately I don't control the pointer value that's stored. The allocating library allows me to ask for a block of memory of any size and it gives me a pointer to it into which I can write what I want (which, with the sub-classing approach, would be the most-derived object that has a T sub-object). At some point it may hand me back the pointer to the memory it allocated as a void*. I'd have no choice but to cast it to whatever I wrote into the memory. That'd be a `Derived<T>*` but I wouldn't know the T at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just write a (constexpr) function to calculate proper padding:

```
template<typename T>
size_t paddingAfterHeader() {
   auto rem = sizeof(Header)%alignof(T);
   return rem ? alignof(T) - rem : 0; 
}
```

allocation:

```
void *mem = malloc( sizeof( Header ) + paddingAfterHeader<T>() + sizeof(T) );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Slava. What would the allocation look like? malloc(sizeof(std::pair<Header, T>))? Edit: I see, I should do malloc(sizeof(Header) + offsetAfterHeader<T>() + sizeof(t))

Comment: @authentec Good question, actually it would be more usable to calculate padding, fixed.

Comment: *Personally, I would write `template <typename T> size_t SizeofHeaderRoundedUp() { return (sizeof(Header)+alignof(T)-1))/alignof(T)*alignof(T); }`  - probably with more lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare the header with maximum alignment, you don't have to worry about the following object requiring additional alignment.

```
#include <cstddef>

struct
alignas(std::max_align_t)
Header
{
    char body[17];
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "size: " << sizeof(Header) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "align: " << alignof(Header) << std::endl;
}
```

On my system, the output is:

```
size: 32
align: 16
```